# append child from the dom into another div, but to stay on the same position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 elements when the yellow div is clicked I want to take the red square put it in that yellow div, but to stay on the same position(when the yellow element is clicked the red must not change position) that it was originally. This is just an example of something I do and both elements are position: absolute, so it should stay like this. Is there a way to do that?
http://jsfiddle.net/9t6n8dmk/25/

EDIT: äs I said I need both elements to be absolute.

```
<div class="square" id="square">
</div>

<span class="image" id="image">
</span>

.square{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  left:100px;
  top:100px;
  background:yellow;
}
.image{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  left:100px;
  top:10px;  
  background: red;
}

let square = document.getElementById("square");
let image = document.getElementById("image");

square.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    square.appendChild(image);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're moving an element into another parent, you have to recalculate the element's position relatively to the new parent:

```js
let square = document.getElementById("square");
let image = document.getElementById("image");

square.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  if (image.parentElement !== square) {
    image.style.top = (image.offsetTop - square.offsetTop) + 'px';
    image.style.left = (image.offsetLeft - square.offsetLeft) + 'px';
    square.appendChild(image);
  }
})
```

```css
.square {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id="square">
</div>

<span class="image" id="image">
</span>
```

Comment: Hello I need to calculate, so the red square stay on the same position it was originally, not on the same position as the yellow square.

Comment: @ivaylo, please run the snippet: when you click on yellow box, the red one becomes its child, but stays on the same place on the screen, does not it?

Comment: @ivaylo, ahhh I see, if you clicked twice it disappeared. Thanks, I've fixed this.

Comment: Ok, I just realised that when you click 2 times it disappears, so I thought it is behind the parent. Yes thank you this is what I wanted!

Comment: Yes, Thanks! My bad